# Combination of past simple and present simple in telling stories

Tags: word-choice, grammar, past-tense

Here is the paragraph from a textbook:

> One day the Princess decided that she **didn't like** staying at home all day. so she told her father that she **wanted** to get a job.

My question is: can I replace *didn't like* with *doesn't like*, and *wanted* with *wants* so the paragraph becomes:

> One day the Princess decided that she **doesn't like** staying at home all day. so she told her father that she **wants** to get a job.

Comment: There are ways to do this, some of them occur naturally, but this particular construction doesn't work. It would read awkward or just wrong to native speakers.

Comment: Unless the Princess exists in the "real" world, *still* doesn't like staying at home, and *still* wants to get a job, you should stick to past tense. Or make the stylistic choice to use present tense throughout (i.e. - use ***decides*** and ***tells*** as well).

Comment: The new version works for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it's not possible to make that change, although there are similar situations where it might be possible.

To make things clearer, here is an example where there is certainly only one correct choice:

> Yesterday, when she saw her father, she told him she **was** hungry.

It is definitely impossible to say *is* here, because the state of her being hungry is in the past. This is the opposite of what is done in Slavic languages, where the equivalent of *is* would be required, because the tense in reported speech is determined from the point of view of the person at the time they're speaking. In English, as in most Germanic and Romance languages, it is the point of view of the narrator that matters.

There are cases in which things are not so clear-cut, however. Here is one case where you have a choice:

> When I met her yesterday, she said that oxygen **was/is** heavier than carbon.

Here, even from the narrator's present perspective, there are two ways of looking at the situation. The first is to consider the statement "Oxygen is heavier than carbon" to be a timeless truth, the time at which the statement was made therefore being irrelevant. This corresponds to the use of *is*. The other possibility is to follow the general rule illustrated above even though in this case the statement refers to a timeless truth.

Here is another situation where you have a choice:

> When we spoke yesterday, she said she **would be/will be** going to Ottawa next week.

(In either case, the words "next week" refer to what would be called "next week" relative to the present, not relative to yesterday.) Here it is again irrelevant whether we view the statement as having been true yesterday when it was made, or as being true now. There is no suggestion that the speaker might have changed her mind, or would say anything different now. Hence both tenses are possible. If the narrator uses "will be," then he is presenting the information as being equivalent in a practical sense whether viewed from the present or from the time it was originally conveyed. Perhaps the most cautious thing to do, if there was any doubt, would be to use *would* (which is the tense we use for the "future in the past").

In the following situation, only *would* is possible.

> When I saw her this morning, she said she **would** have lunch with me tomorrow. But soon afterwards she phoned to cancel.

To return to your example, here is another sentence that *is* possible.

> Yesterday Jane told me she **doesn't** like staying home all day. She **is** looking for a job.

However, in your example, the princess is a character in a story that is being narrated in the past tense. The princess doesn't exist in the present, so it would make no sense to say that she "doesn't" like staying home all day.

Comment: This answer is filled with excellent information, lucidly presented. But I don't think it answers the question. The question, as I understand it (perhaps wrongly), is about the "historical present": the use of the present tense to describe past events when telling a story, and how/whether that clashes with the past tense in the same context. Maybe you could save most of this answer for a question about indirect discourse?

Comment: @BenKovitz My interpretation was different. As I said in my answer, there are languages is in which you are required to say things like "She said she will see me yesterday" - the tense is determined relative to the time of the utterance, not relative to the time that the speech is reported. My impression is that the OP may speak a language of that kind. I don't think the question is about the historical present, because otherwise the OP would have written "decide**s** that she doesn't like staying home all day" and "tell**s** her father that...," which he didn't do.

Comment: In fact, @user49640, you knew what was the purpose of my question. I speak Arabic natively which is similar to Slavic languages regarding this issue. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can, for reasons of style, if you also change the other verbs there too to the present tense:

One day the Princess *decides* that she doesn't like staying at home all day, so she *tells* her father that she wants to get a job....

EDIT:

There is more laxity in how you phrase things, when you're telling a story.  But you can't have jarring changes.  For instance you could have the intro in the past but then starting with a new paragraph come to the present and stay there.  Present tense brings the readers into closer contact with the story, so it's an interesting choice, and there is a tradition behind it too, so readers won't be shocked by that change.  However, then you got to stick to it.  Also, be careful with your punctuation.